# Combining date and time into a Date column for plotting

Tags: r, plot

I want to create a line plot. I have 3 columns in my data frame:

```
date        time   numbers
01-02-2010  14:57  5
01-02-2010  23:23  7
02-02-2010  05:05  3
02-02-2010  10:23  11
```

How can I combine the first two columns and make a plot based on date and time ? 
Date is Date class, time is just a char variable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reconstruct your data:

```
dat <- read.table(text="
date        time   numbers
01-02-2010  14:57  5
01-02-2010  23:23  7
02-02-2010  05:05  3
02-02-2010  10:23  11", header=TRUE)
```

Now use `as.POSIXct()` and `paste()` to combine your date and time into a POSIX date.  You need to specify the format, using the symbols defined in `?strptime`.  Also see `?DateTimeClasses` for more information

```
dat$newdate <- with(dat, as.POSIXct(paste(date, time), format="%m-%d-%Y %H:%M"))
plot(numbers ~ newdate, data=dat, type="b", col="blue")
```

[image]

Comment: This returns NA as newdate, I tried playing with it around and converting dates first to date class with as.Date. But still without success.

#data$DateTime <- strptime(paste(data$Date, data$Time),format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

I managed to do it with this, but I'm not sure on how to subset data
since data$DateTime > "01-02-2010 00:00:00" doesn't work.

Comment: It works with the sample date you provided.  Please try and trace the problem to data that doesn't work and include this in your question.

Comment: @user1927971 The format string in your comment has a seconds field. If you use that on the data in your question, you will get NAs. Does you actual data have a seconds field?

Answer (score 21):

The `lubridate` package is another option. It handles most of the fussy formatting details, so it can be easier to use than base `R` date functions. For example, in your case, `mdy_hm` (month-day-year_hour-minute) will convert your `date` and `time` variables into a single POSIXct date-time column. (If you meant it to be day-month-year, rather than month-day-year, then just use `dmy_hm`.) See code below.

```
library(lubridate)

dat$date_time = mdy_hm(paste(dat$date, dat$time))

dat
        date  time numbers           date_time
1 01-02-2010 14:57       5 2010-01-02 14:57:00
2 01-02-2010 23:23       7 2010-01-02 23:23:00
3 02-02-2010 05:05       3 2010-02-02 05:05:00
4 02-02-2010 10:23      11 2010-02-02 10:23:00

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(date_time, numbers)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_line() +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks=date_breaks("1 week"),
                   minor_breaks=date_breaks("1 day"))
```

[image]