# Converting date and time in a list of values

Tags: r, type-conversion

I've read [Combining date and time into a Date column for plotting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105984/combining-date-and-time-into-a-date-column-for-plotting) and other related solutions, but couldn't find an answer to this one:
I have a list of strings having 7 elements, where the first two are date and time:

```
> head(IOlow)
[1] "20160928 142949 0.000172 0.000225 0.000015 0.000172 0.000765"
[2] "20160928 164105 0.000163 0.000227 0.000017 0.000163 0.000908"
[3] "20160928 172826 0.000176 0.000238 0.000017 0.000173 0.001604"
```

Now I want to replace each such string with a list containing 6 elements, where the first element is a DateTime object built from the first two numbers, and the others are floating-point numbers (and not strings). So I defined this helper function:

```
dateFormat <- "%Y%m%d %H%M%S"
function (x) {
    x <- strsplit(x, split=" ")
    w <- paste(x[[1]][1], x[[1]][2])
    str(w)
    x <- list(as.POSIXlt(w, format=dateFormat), as.double(x[[1]][3:7]))
}
```

(`str(w)` is for debugging only)
When applying this function like this

```
lapply(head(IOlow), to_numeric)
```

the result looks like this:

```
> lapply(head(IOlow), to_numeric)
 chr "20160928 142949"
 chr "20160928 164105"
 chr "20160928 172826"
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "2016-09-28 14:29:49 CEST"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 0.000172 0.000225 0.000015 0.000172 0.000765


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "2016-09-28 16:41:05 CEST"

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 0.000163 0.000227 0.000017 0.000163 0.000908


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "2016-09-28 17:28:26 CEST"

[[3]][[2]]
[1] 0.000176 0.000238 0.000017 0.000173 0.001604
```

For reasons I don't understand, R seems to make extra lists in lists (I think I cannot return a vector as there are different data types in the list).
Maybe it's just that some functions are not documented in the way I need it to understand what's really going on.

The next step would build a data.frame from the list of lists.

What did I do wrong, and how would I do it correctly?

System info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.1
```

Comment: Do you *need* to use `POSIXlt`? It stores things internally as a list (which can be both good and bad). I tend to use `POSIXct` more for various reasons.

Comment: To clear some confusion, could you provide the desired output? As far as I understand, in the end you want to see a data frame with 6 columns as in 1 for date and 5 for data? How about skipping all this "list mess" altogether by designing function that directly converts your input to data frame?

Comment: Actually up to your post I didn't really know what the difference between `POSIXct` and `POSIXlt` is (thanks!). Maybe the documentation could be improved. Regarding the output format: The first list element should be something that can be used by plot and displayed in human readable format as date and/or time in later processing (and the rest is the remaining elements as processable numbers). Clear enough? I'm open to any elegant solution (as I'm still learning R)!

Answer (score 2):

On the lines of what @A.Val suggested, do you have to deal with it as lists? If it's directly in a file somewhere, it'll read in more directly with something like `read.delim` or perhaps `readr::read_delim`.

Lacking that, taking your strings and turning it into a fake file (for two reasons: (1) your reproducibility, and (2) if you cannot deal with it as a file, now you can still use this answer):

```
IOlow <- c("20160928 142949 0.000172 0.000225 0.000015 0.000172 0.000765",
           "20160928 164105 0.000163 0.000227 0.000017 0.000163 0.000908",
           "20160928 172826 0.000176 0.000238 0.000017 0.000173 0.001604")
dat <- read.delim(textConnection(paste(IOlow, collapse = "\n")),
                  sep = " ", header = FALSE)
dat
#         V1     V2       V3       V4      V5       V6       V7
# 1 20160928 142949 0.000172 0.000225 1.5e-05 0.000172 0.000765
# 2 20160928 164105 0.000163 0.000227 1.7e-05 0.000163 0.000908
# 3 20160928 172826 0.000176 0.000238 1.7e-05 0.000173 0.001604

dat$dt <- as.POSIXct(paste(dat$V1, dat$V2, sep = " "), format = "%Y%m%d %H%M%S")
dat <- dat[, -(1:2)]
dat
#         V3       V4      V5       V6       V7                  dt
# 1 0.000172 0.000225 1.5e-05 0.000172 0.000765 2016-09-28 14:29:49
# 2 0.000163 0.000227 1.7e-05 0.000163 0.000908 2016-09-28 16:41:05
# 3 0.000176 0.000238 1.7e-05 0.000173 0.001604 2016-09-28 17:28:26
```

Comment: Rather cool: I didn't think of `read.delim()` in this context. Also removing the first two columns using `dat[, -(1:2)]` was new to me (or hadn't settled in my memory).

Comment: There are several ways to skin this cat, frankly. It can also be done (`dplyr`-fluidly) with `readr::read_delim` (from a file), `tidyr::unite`, `lubridate::ymd_hms`, and `dplyr` to glue it all together. I'm sure it can be done with `data.table`, though I don't know it well enough. `strsplit` can work if you absolutely have to work with it as a vector of strings.

Comment: BTW: an oft-forgotten step or check is to ensure the timezone is correct. It's times like these when "explicit" will save much headache down the road.

Comment: Explanation why I can't start with `readr::read_delim` (not obvious from the example given): This was my first attempt to process a plain text log file, and the results in `IOlow` are actually the result of filtering and text-replacing (regex) the lines in the log file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this, don't you?

```
to_numeric <- function(x,dateFormat) {
  x <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), split=" "))
  w <- paste(x[1], x[2])
  x <- list(as.POSIXlt(w, format=dateFormat), as.double(x[3:7]))
}

l <- apply(head(IOlow), 1, function(x) to_numeric(x, '%Y%m%d'))

l[1]

[[1]]
[1] "2016-09-28 IST"

[[2]]
[1] 0.000172 0.000225 0.000015 0.000172 0.000765
```

Comment: Not quite (I'm unsure I got it all): I thought `strsplit()` returns a list of elements; so what is the result of `unlist(strsplit(...))`? OK, for some obscure reason ` strsplit()` returns a list which only element is a list of the resulting elements. What's the reason for the `1` argument to `apply()`?

Comment: (Hit Enter too early) It seems R likes to put lists in lists, just because it's so cool (or to confuse the ...) ;-) The solution of @r2evans looks better to me, but still this is useful as well.

Comment: (1) since it's better if have 6 values in a vector, instead of a list, you need just one level of indexing: just x[1], not x[[1]][1]
(2) for each row of the dataframe IOlow, we want to apply the function, that's why there is the argument 1
(3) it's good to have an additional dateFormat argument passed to your function to make it more flexible.
(4) Finally each of the row of the dataframe will now correposnd to an element (which is itself a list with 6 elements) in the output list.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that

```
dat <- read.delim(textConnection(paste(IOlow, collapse = "\n")),
                  sep = " ", header = FALSE)
```

in the answer of @r2evans first converts the list to text (`paste`), then parses the text (`read.delim(textConnection(...))`), I considered that to be too complex. So I redesigned the logic:

```
split_line <- function (x) {
    x <- unlist(strsplit(x, split=" "))
}

IOlow <- lapply(IOlow, split_line)
IOlow <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, IOlow), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Then I build a new "when" variable from date and time (I had added names to the data.frame):

```
dateFormat <- "%Y%m%d %H%M%S"
IOlow$when <- with(IOlow,
                   as.POSIXct(paste(date, time, sep = " "), format=dateFormat))
```

Then I drop the date and time variables (`IOlow <- IOlow[, -(1:2)]`). Finally I convert the remaining strings to double (Is there a more elegant solution to this step?):

```
for (n in names(IOlow)) {
    # convert all strings to double
    if ("character" %in% class(IOlow[,n])) {
        IOlow[n] <- lapply(IOlow[n], as.double)
    }
}
```

Comment: You say *"too complex"*, but you are ingest the data *raw*, doing regex work in R, and then trying to parse a delimited file? Efficiency is certainly out the window (esp since you are having to convert manually to float), and by using `read.delim` (or related functions), you're capitalizing on their ability to deal robustly with the near-raw data as well as number-ify things. Over to you, but I contend that this approach -- though it may work -- is more fragile and likely slower.

Comment: Having said that, I've had similar needs and I found the *fastest* (time-wise) and *safest* way was to use `readLines`, massage the data as needed (e.g., regex massaging), `writeLines` back to another file, then `readr::read_csv`. The difference in time doing it this was was *significant*, not to be discarded lightly. (I should have used python for the pre-read massaging, frankly, but I suspect I'm like you here in that R is closest and being used for everything else, so ...).

Comment: Maybe @r2evans shows a sketch of the code being used for the "massage" (as a general solution to related problems)? I didn't mean to discredit the proposal, but I felt it wouldn't fit well in my case.

Comment: There's no general solution: it's specific to the data and the problems that need to be fixed in order to use the standard `read.*` functions. It would be more appropriate for you to show what your data looks like before you fix it into a vector of 7-field strings.