# Trying to combine dates and times

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate, stringr

I am trying to combine dates and times. These are from a file when imported, looks like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

bookings <- structure(list(booking_date = structure(c(1549670400, 1550275200, 
    1550880000, 1551484800, 1552089600, 1552694400), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), start_time = structure(c(-2209043700, 
    -2209043700, -2209043700, -2209043700, -2209043700, -2209043700
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Which looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  booking_date        start_time         
  <dttm>              <dttm>             
1 2019-02-09 00:00:00 1899-12-31 08:45:00
2 2019-02-16 00:00:00 1899-12-31 08:45:00
3 2019-02-23 00:00:00 1899-12-31 08:45:00
4 2019-03-02 00:00:00 1899-12-31 08:45:00
5 2019-03-09 00:00:00 1899-12-31 08:45:00
6 2019-03-16 00:00:00 1899-12-31 08:45:00
```

Obviously the date in the `start_time` column is wrong. It should be combined with the booking date, so that the first row should read `2019-02-09 08:45:00`.

What would the best way of doing that be? I have tried this ([based on this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105984/combining-date-and-time-into-a-date-column-for-plotting)), which doesn't really work in my situation.

```
bookings %>% 
  select(booking_date, start_time) %>% 
  mutate(time_2 = as.character(start_time)) %>% 
  mutate(time_3 = str_sub(time_2, -8, -1)) %>% 
  mutate(booking_start = dmy(paste(booking_date, time_3)))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get date for `start_time` from `booking_date` a base R approach would be to `paste` "Date" part from  `booking_date` and "time" part from `start_time` and convert them to `POSIXct`.

```
bookings$start_time <- as.POSIXct(paste(as.Date(bookings$booking_date), 
                                  format(bookings$start_time, "%T")))

bookings
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#  booking_date        start_time         
#  <dttm>              <dttm>             
#1 2019-02-09 00:00:00 2019-02-09 08:45:00
#2 2019-02-16 00:00:00 2019-02-16 08:45:00
#3 2019-02-23 00:00:00 2019-02-23 08:45:00
#4 2019-03-02 00:00:00 2019-03-02 08:45:00
#5 2019-03-09 00:00:00 2019-03-09 08:45:00
#6 2019-03-16 00:00:00 2019-03-16 08:45:00
```

If you want to use it in pipes you can do

```
library(dplyr)
bookings %>%
  mutate(start_time = as.POSIXct(paste(as.Date(booking_date), 
                      format(start_time, "%T"))))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can also do this with `lubridate::date`.

`date() <-` lets you set the date component of a date/time object:

```
# Set the date component of start_time to be the date component of booking_date
date(bookings$start_time) <- bookings$booking_date

bookings

# A tibble: 6 x 2
  booking_date        start_time         
  <dttm>              <dttm>             
1 2019-02-09 00:00:00 2019-02-09 08:45:00
2 2019-02-16 00:00:00 2019-02-16 08:45:00
3 2019-02-23 00:00:00 2019-02-23 08:45:00
4 2019-03-02 00:00:00 2019-03-02 08:45:00
5 2019-03-09 00:00:00 2019-03-09 08:45:00
6 2019-03-16 00:00:00 2019-03-16 08:45:00
```

Since it uses assignment (`<-`), you can't use this first method as part of a pipe. What does work in a pipe, is the `update.POSIXt` method (see `?DateTimeUpdate`), which lets you update the date components of a date, though you have to specify each part of the components specifically:

```
library(lubridate)

bookings %>%
    mutate(date_time = update(start_time,
                              year = year(booking_date),
                              month = month(booking_date),
                              day  = day(booking_date)))

  booking_date        start_time          date_time          
  <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>             
1 2019-02-09 00:00:00 1899-12-31 08:45:00 2019-02-09 08:45:00
2 2019-02-16 00:00:00 1899-12-31 08:45:00 2019-02-16 08:45:00
3 2019-02-23 00:00:00 1899-12-31 08:45:00 2019-02-23 08:45:00
4 2019-03-02 00:00:00 1899-12-31 08:45:00 2019-03-02 08:45:00
5 2019-03-09 00:00:00 1899-12-31 08:45:00 2019-03-09 08:45:00
6 2019-03-16 00:00:00 1899-12-31 08:45:00 2019-03-16 08:45:00
```

Comment: Is there a way to pipe this instead of using the `$`?